# How do you explain why the arguments of $\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)$ aren't "backwards"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, notation, homological-algebra, derived-functors

For objects $A$ and $B$ In an abelian category, $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ is the group of morphisms $$A \longrightarrow B\,.$$ Now $\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)$, the derived functor of $\operatorname{Hom},$ can be thought of as the group of extensions of $A$ by $B$, so short exact sequences (up to equivalence) of the form $$B \hookrightarrow \_\_ \twoheadrightarrow A\,.$$ It looks like $A$ and $B$ have switched places. If we insist that arrows go from left to right, then naïvely thinking about it $\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)$ should be sequences that start with $A$ on the left and end with $B$ on the right, like with $\operatorname{Hom}$. Now $A$ and $B$ aren't *really* backwards, and this makes sense somehow, but I've never thought much of it until seeing fellow students make the naïve mistake I mentioned. How can you briefly explain to someone that this isn't a notational quirk, but, relating $\operatorname{Ext}$ to $\operatorname{Hom}$, this actually makes sense?

Comment: I believe that the notation is because Ext functors are derived functors of the Hom functor, so keeping the left/right variable of the Hom in the same place makes the comparison apparent.

Comment: I think it's a good question.  I remember asking the very same of my doctoral advisor many years ago, and he really let me have it for not seeing the Hom answer.  So, good for you for asking here instead of asking your advisor.  (Unless the answerer below is your advisor...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The machinery of derived categories makes this much more intuitive.  In particular, an element of $\operatorname{Ext}^1(A,B)$ can be identified with a morphism $A\to B[1]$ in the derived category (where $A$ and $B$ are considered as objects in the derived category by treating them as chain complexes concentrated in degree $0$).  Taking the fiber of this morphism, we get an object $C$ in the derived category and an exact triangle $$B\to C\to A\to B[1].$$  Looking at the associated long exact sequence of homology objects, since $B$ and $A$ have homology concentrated in degree $0$, so does $C$, and the long exact sequence on homology just turns into a short exact sequence $$0\to B\to C\to A\to 0$$ where now $C$ represents the $0$th homology of the derived object $C$ we had before.  That's an extension of $A$ by $B$!  Conversely, given such an extension, we can consider $A,B,$ and $C$ as objects in the derived category and get an exact triangle $B\to C\to A\to B[1]$ as above and in particular we get a derived morphism $A\to B[1]$, and these two constructions can be shown to be inverse.

Or, without the language of derived categories, we should think of an extension $$0\to B\to C\to A\to 0$$ as "going from $A$ to $B$" since when you look at long exact sequences associated to this short exact sequence, the *connecting homomorphisms* of the long exact sequence go from $A$ to $B$ (with a degree shift).  Those connecting homomorphisms correspond exactly to the morphism $A\to B[1]$ in the derived category.

Comment: This is also my answer. From the perspective of algebraic topology we can think of $B[1]$ as the "classifying space of extensions by $B$." This perspective cleanly explains, among other things, why Ext is contravariant in the first variable and covariant in the second, a feature it shares with Hom, and which is a bit harder to see thinking only in terms of extensions; here it's just the usual functoriality of Hom, but applied to morphisms $A \to B[1]$.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the long exact sequence. $Ext(A,B)$ extends the sequence $0\to Hom(A,B)\to Hom(A,B')\to Hom(A,B'')$ when $B\to B'\to B''$ is short exact. More broadly it is the derived functor of $Hom(A,-)$ or of $Hom(-,B)$, and more abstractly it's the homs from $A$ to the suspension of $B$ in the derived category. All in all, unless the only way you've seen $Ext$ is as a set of extensions, which seems pedagogically rare, then there's plenty of reason to write the arguments in the correct order.

Comment: Then I was the result of a pedagogically rarity for awhile. :) I first saw $\mathrm{Ext}$ looking at Hall algebras of exact hereditary categories, so $\mathrm{Ext}^i$ vanishes for $i>1$. There was no need to think of $\mathrm{Ext}^1$ besides just as extensions, and I didn't see the definition as a derived functor until taking a homological algebra class. So while I understand what you're saying, it may just be my lack of fluency in homological algebra, I'm not quite *satisfied* with your answer yet.

Comment: @MikePierce That's interesting! I can imagine that if the notation hadn't been borrowed from homological algebra, it might have gone in the opposite order.